# Instruments.app crash when profiling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, instruments

Instruments.app crashes when I try to profile on the device.  It works fine in the simulator.

This happens with all instruments- time profiler, leaks, etc.  I am able to use the energy diagnostics instrument.

I tried:

- Made sure app was set to debug mode (also tried with release mode)
- Reinstalling xcode
- Rebooting device/computer
- Attaching to process once app is running

My main device is an iPhone 4 running 5.1, jailbroken but this also happens on a non-jailbroken iPhone running 4.3.x

Please let me know if you have any thoughts on why this is happening.

Partial crash log below

```
Process:         Instruments [12983]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/Instruments
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Instruments
Version:         4.3 (4321)
Build Info:      Instruments-4321000000000000~2
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [253]

Date/Time:       2012-06-08 16:27:06.214 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.4 (11E53)
Report Version:  9
Sleep/Wake UUID: 1556D9E2-2B8A-4A76-A591-F8ACEF479C31

Interval Since Last Report:          24319 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           8
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  13147 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   7
Anonymous UUID:                      A73B414D-9FB6-4055-94D3-A887EB7ADFFD

Crashed Thread:  7

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000004

VM Regions Near 0x4:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000101a71000-0000000101a76000 [   20K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/Instruments

Application Specific Information:
objc[12983]: garbage collection is OFF

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff849ab67a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff849aad71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff826899bf io_service_get_matching_services + 210
3   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff82641604 IOServiceGetMatchingServices + 137
4   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff82641741 IOServiceGetMatchingService + 25
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85f7710b +[NSFileWrapper _canSafelyMapFilesAtPath:] + 241
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85f1c510 -[NSData(NSData) initWithContentsOfFile:options:error:] + 139
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85f83b48 -[NSData(NSData) initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:] + 238
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89e6e387 NSImageRepNewDataFromFileURL + 247
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89aa00fc +[NSImageRep _imageRepsWithContentsOfURL:expandImageContentNow:giveUpOnNetworkURLsWithoutGoodExtensions:] + 548
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a9fe9a __-[NSImageURLReferencingRepProvider representations]_block_invoke_1 + 48
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85f34347 _NSFaultInObject + 35
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a70ae7 -[NSImageURLReferencingRepProvider representations] + 80
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a9fd7e __-[NSImage size]_block_invoke_1 + 353
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a2b825 -[NSImage _usingRepProviderPerformBlock:] + 37
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a596c2 -[NSImage size] + 129
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a9f9a6 -[NSImage alignmentRect] + 51
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89b08de5 -[NSImageCell _imageRectForDrawing:inFrame:inView:] + 43
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89b08c6b -[NSImageCell drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:] + 541
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89b08a28 -[NSImageCell drawWithFrame:inView:] + 1705
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a9ddb7 -[NSControl drawRect:] + 398
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a6997a -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 3758
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a96b4f -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 1583
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a96f7b -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2651
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a96f7b -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2651
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a96f7b -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2651
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a96f7b -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2651
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a96f7b -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2651
28  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a96f7b -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2651
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a96f7b -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2651
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a66f55 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 1032
31  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a6644f -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 270
32  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a6186f -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 4755
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a5a2ed -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1676
34  com.apple.dt.instruments.InstrumentsKit 0x0000000101a8e155 -[XRSplitViewAnimation setCurrentProgress:] + 81
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89bec62d -[NSAnimation(NSInternal) _advanceTimeWithTimer:] + 156
36  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85f4ef40 __NSFireTimer + 102
37  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8689b934 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
38  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8689b486 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 534
39  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8687be11 __CFRunLoopRun + 1617
40  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8687b486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
41  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85f02f7b -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 267
42  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89cc956c -[NSAnimation(NSInternal) _runBlocking] + 365
43  com.apple.dt.instruments.InstrumentsKit 0x0000000101a8e058 -[XRHorizontalFillSplitView animateSplitFromPosition:toPosition:] + 377
44  com.apple.dt.instruments.InstrumentsKit 0x0000000101a8dc86 -[PFTTraceDocument animateLowerVisibility:] + 215
45  com.apple.dt.instruments.InstrumentsKit 0x0000000101aaa3e5 -[PFTTraceDocument toggleDetail:] + 71
46  com.apple.dt.instruments.InstrumentsKit 0x0000000101aaa320 -[PFTTraceDocument _didStartCommand:] + 238
47  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85f0dd0e __-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_1 + 47
48  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8688f7ba _CFXNotificationPost + 2634
49  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85ef9fc3 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 65
50  com.apple.dt.instruments.InstrumentsPlugIn  0x0000000101c5f8c7 -[XRTrace startCommandWithPurpose:] + 1546
51  com.apple.dt.instruments.InstrumentsKit 0x0000000101aa8d4d -[PFTTraceDocument startRun] + 164
52  com.apple.dt.instruments.InstrumentsKit 0x0000000101aa8b55 -[PFTTraceDocument recordTrace:] + 599
53  com.apple.dt.instruments.InstrumentsKit 0x0000000101ae370d -[PFTDocumentController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:error:] + 2769
54  com.apple.dt.instruments.InstrumentsKit 0x0000000101ae3f3a -[PFTDocumentController _templateChooserActionEnded:returnCode:contextInfo:] + 494
55  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89cd13df -[NSApplication endSheet:returnCode:] + 275
56  com.apple.imageKit              0x00007fff896992fb -[IKImageBrowserView(ImageBrowserEvents) mouseUp:] + 649
57  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89aea40e -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6504
58  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a83a55 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5593
59  com.apple.dt.Instruments        0x0000000101a7339f 0x101a71000 + 9119
60  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a1a0c6 -[NSApplication run] + 555
61  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89c96244 NSApplicationMain + 867
62  com.apple.dt.Instruments        0x0000000101a73724 0x101a71000 + 10020
```

Comment: You should post the crash log, someone may have run into the same issue. Plus it's just always a good idea to do so, otherwise the answers will be strictly guesses.

Comment: same thing happens to me every single time. I'm going to WWDC this year so I'll be asking the guys who made Instruments about it. So annoying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be fixed with Instruments 4.4

Comment: Maybe your specific issue was fixed nowadays, but Instruments is a really buggy mess made by Apple team, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69424620/8740349