# Xcode Instruments's "Time Profiler" crashes instantly

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

Why does Instrument's "`Time Profiler`" crash?
(while "Allocations" works just fine)

### What I tried:

1. Running just for Instrument purpose.
2. Attaching to an already launched App later (instead of running).
3. Launch "Allocations" first, then in "Instruments", clicking the "+" button causes same issue (when selecting "Time Profiler").
4. Retry with both Build-Configurations (Debug and Release).
5. Clearing build directory, then retrying all of above.

### Crash report:

```
Crashed Thread:        3  Dispatch queue: com.apple.dt.frame.activity

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [13064]

// ...

Thread 3 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.dt.frame.activity
0   com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x00000001082497f3 std::__1::__hash_iterator<std::__1::__hash_node<void*, void*>*> std::__1::__hash_table<void*, std::__1::hash<void*>, std::__1::equal_to<void*>, std::__1::allocator<void*> >::find<void*>(void* const&) + 83
1   com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x0000000108249044 XRCLIPS::_delegateCallbackRouter(environmentData*, udfContext*, udfValue*) + 628
2   com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x00000001083018a0 EvaluateExpression + 464
3   com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x00000001083069a8 PutProcBind + 216
4   com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x0000000108301a89 EvaluateExpression + 953
5   com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x00000001081e61ab PrognFunction + 75
6   com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x00000001083018a0 EvaluateExpression + 464
7   com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x000000010830887c EvaluateProcActions + 604
8   com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x000000010832b357 Run + 2327
9   com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x000000010832c312 RunCommand + 130
10  com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x00000001083018a0 EvaluateExpression + 464
11  com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x00000001081e61ab PrognFunction + 75
12  com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x00000001083018a0 EvaluateExpression + 464
13  com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x000000010830887c EvaluateProcActions + 604
14  com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x00000001081f4cc7 CallDeffunction + 391
15  com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x000000010831df17 EvaluateDeffunctionCall + 39
16  com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x0000000108301a89 EvaluateExpression + 953
17  com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x00000001082b0478 RouteCommand + 1128
18  com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x000000010824acdc invocation function for block in XRCLIPS::executeCommand(NSString*, NSString*) + 684
19  com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x000000010824a7c3 _runInCLocale(void () block_pointer) + 51
20  com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x000000010824a9dc XRCLIPS::executeCommand(NSString*, NSString*) + 124
21  com.apple.dt.InstrumentsAnalysisCore    0x00000001082c369d -[XRAnalysisCoreBindingHemisphere solveBindingProblem] + 109
22  com.apple.dt.instruments.InstrumentsPlugIn  0x00000001087c6835 -[XRAnalysisCoreSetupAgent _solveBindingProblem:] + 130
23  com.apple.dt.instruments.InstrumentsPlugIn  0x00000001087c5b8c -[XRAnalysisCoreSetupAgent executeStopOnItinerary:] + 695
24  com.apple.dt.instruments.DVTInstrumentsUtilities    0x0000000107fa40e4 -[XRMobileAgent(XRMobileAgentStop) hello] + 272
25  com.apple.dt.instruments.DVTInstrumentsUtilities    0x0000000107fa041d __51-[XRFrameActivityManager _reevaluateArrivingAgent:]_block_invoke + 112
26  com.apple.dt.instruments.DVTInstrumentsUtilities    0x0000000107fa7fc3 xray::scheduler::ActivityManager::_processActivity(void*) + 115
27  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff67acf658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
28  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff67ad4c44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff67ad55d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff67adec09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
31  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff67d2da3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
32  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff67d2cb77 start_wqthread + 15

// ...

Thread 3 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000007fb2  rbx: 0x0000000000000004  rcx: 0x8ddf04fbc068655b  rdx: 0x1124171e0a32926b
  rdi: 0x00007fb2984d6258  rsi: 0x00007fb29ca7f7a0  rbp: 0x00007000011afe70  rsp: 0x00007000011afe70
   r8: 0x9ddfea08eb382d69   r9: 0x0000000000000002  r10: 0x00007fff85335500  r11: 0x00007fff2d9e6128
  r12: 0x00007fb299af8460  r13: 0x00007000011aff30  r14: 0x0000000000000004  r15: 0x00007fff6697dca0
  rip: 0x00000001082497f3  rfl: 0x0000000000010a03  cr2: 0x00000001081f1a10
  
Logical CPU:     1
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     6

// ...

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=828.9M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=828.9M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=100.2M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=100.2M(100%)
 
                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Accelerate framework               384K        3 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
CG backing stores                  224K        2 
CG image                           116K       18 
CG raster data                     216K       11 
CoreAnimation                     7068K       56 
CoreGraphics                         8K        1 
CoreImage                           20K        5 
CoreUI image data                 1296K       18 
Dispatch continuations            4096K        1 
Foundation                           4K        1 
IOKit                             7940K        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                            70.3M      113 
MALLOC guard page                   32K        8 
OpenGL GLSL                        256K        3 
STACK GUARD                       56.1M       14 
Stack                             14.6M       14 
VM_ALLOCATE                        368K       21 
VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)            2048K        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
__DATA                            77.0M      576 
__DATA_CONST                      1957K       73 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__GLSLBUILTINS                    5176K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       409.5M      118 
__OBJC_RO                         32.3M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         1908K        2 
__TEXT                           419.8M      548 
__UNICODE                          564K        1 
mapped file                      132.1M       42 
shared memory                      632K       14 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.2G     1671 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.2G     1671
```

More info:

```
Process:               Instruments [13064]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode_12.4.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/Instruments
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Instruments
Instruments Version:   12.4 (64543.2)
Build Info:            Instruments-64543002000000000~11 (12D4e)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Instruments [13064]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2021-10-03 16:02:23.335 +0430
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.7 (19H2)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        3AB66FC9-BBB6-ACB0-2877-9239C69E7BC1

Sleep/Wake UUID:       D2B09D01-75C0-4596-810A-69604C2B70E3

Time Awake Since Boot: 19000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       19000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

// ...

Model: MacBookPro7,1, BootROM 68.0.0.0.0, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.62f7
Graphics: kHW_NVidiaGeForce320MItem, NVIDIA GeForce 320M, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235533654465238432D47372020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235533654465238432D47372020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.102.31)
Bluetooth: Version 7.0.6f7, 3 services, 25 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Network Service: iPhone, Ethernet, en3
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK2555GSXF, 250.06 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: SAMSUNG_Android
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: iPhone
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: Crash reports for Apple tools should go to Apple, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: The report is just to help answerers; the actual question is obvious.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. The original question is not a stack overflow question. Sorry you're crashing but there's nothing we can do or say about it. You need to contact Apple about this.

Comment: Probably irrelevant but: 4GB RAM? Really?

Comment: From which 1GB is most times free (if I close browser and unnecessary stuff; once running Instruments, about 600MB remains). But I know many ppl who install 16GB and think they need more :)

Comment: It happens for all targets, but I need it for iOS only (I develop for macOS in Xcode 11; question is about version 12.4, which has separate Instruments app).

Comment: @Rob I need some time to do these (and will notify later about the result; I hope it's not related to having multiple Xcode versions installed).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237759/discussion-between-rob-and-top-master).

Answer (score 0):

After trying the comment's suggestions (which did not fix issue), like:

- Empty the whole “`derived data`” folder and reboot the Mac.
- [Uninstall Xcode](https://osxdaily.com/2012/02/20/uninstall-xcode) and reinstall it.
- Ensure the desired Xcode version is selected (found in “Xcode” » “Preferences” » “Locations”)

I noticed that "Time Profiler" of `Xcode 12.4` is not compatible with `macOS Catalina` <sup>(version 10.15.7)</sup>.

So, the solution seems to be; never use latest `Xcode` with older `macOS`, it's simply not backward compatible, **well it is backward compatible**, but not fully (in some cases, like my question).

> **Note** that this Q/A is about **`iOS`**, and `Xcode 12.4` has not even SDK for running on `macOS 10.15.x`.